# Twitter Bootstrap responsive css is not generated form the less files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've downloaded the .less files from the [download with docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) link and I have added it to my project. I've alo downloaded less.js and added it to my project. If I include the following in the head of a page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="@routes.Assets.at("less/bootstrap.less")">
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("less/less-1.3.0.min.js")"></script>
```

The bootstrap seems to work, minus the responsive part (i.e. the navbar won't collapse if the browser window becomes too narrow). I can fix this by manually adding bootstrap-responsive.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css")" />
```

The problem is that if I want to modify the color theme of my page, I need to edit the color values in bootstrap-responsive.css, which is a pain. It looks like some of the .less files were meant to generate bootstrap-responsive.css (for example responsive-navabar.less), but they aren't working.

Any advice on how I can get the bootstrap-responsive.css file from the .less files?

Comment: Important Note!
The responsive.less should be placed near the end of your imports. Not in the grid system and page structure.
I place it at the bottom of in components nav

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to explicitly include also this file:

```
responsive.less
```

Assuming you are using recent version (2.0.x) of Twitter Bootstrap.

As mentioned on their website (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive):

> Bootstrap doesn't automatically include these media queries, but understanding and adding them is very easy and requires minimal setup. **You have a few options for including the responsive features of Bootstrap**:
>
> 1. Use the compiled responsive version, bootstrap-responsive.css
> 2. Add @import "responsive.less" and recompile Bootstrap
> 3. Modify and recompile responsive.less as a separate file
>
> Why not just include it? Truth be told, not everything needs to be responsive. Instead of encouraging developers to remove this feature, we figure it best to enable it.

Comment: @JeromyFrench: What is the relation between the question you have linked and this question? It is not obvious, looking solely at the question you have linked.

Comment: both questions deal generally with Bootstrap LESS and specifically with strategies for customizing Bootstrap CSS via the LESS source ("...if I want to modify the color theme of my page..."). I'll remove if you don't think it helpful (or perhaps I should have commented the question and not your answer).